# How to make responsive horizontal grids?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How to make 3 horizontal responsive grid without any framework? Only using CSS and HTML? I tried but I don't have any ideas how to do it.

[image: picture]

Comment: It would be easier if you went into detail on what kind of horizontal grid you're looking for.

Comment: can you tell me where can I found it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a parent div to set the total height (in my example it's 300px but you can set it to 100% as well).

Then set the height of each child div to 33% `height: 33%`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxod93nv/)

[Another example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxod93nv/1/) with total height set to 100%. Note that in order for that to work you must set the height of the html and body to 100% as well.